# wait for each element

Tags: node.js, async-await

I need to wait each item, than call another function.

```
await readCSV(filename).then(fileArray => {
        for (let element of fileArray) { 
            console.log(element)
            searchItem(element) //<--- Wait each element will finish this function()
        }
    })
```

the function of `searchItem()` is:

```
async function searchItem(item) {
    console.log('2) Avvio Browser for ' + item.codice_kromeda)
    await page.goto('url_part1' + item.codice_kromeda + 'url_part2');

    await page.waitForSelector('.si-search-result')
    let list = await page.$$('.si-search-result');

    console.log(list)
    return true
}
```

Comment: You would have to show the code for `searchItem()` got anyone to have any idea how to help.

Comment: done. added. im sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `searchItem()` already returns a promise that resolves when the search is complete, you can simply restructure to properly use `await`:

```
const fileArray = await readCSV(filename);
for (let element of fileArray) { 
    console.log(element);
    await searchItem(element);
}
```